# use 'id name ends with' inside on() for dynamic binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple select type input HTML fields getting dynamically generated inside my form. I want to dynamically bind the item field to the change event.

item field looks like this:

the id of item field generated is like this

- `id="id_form-0-item"`
- `id="id_form-1-item"`
- `id="id_form-2-item"`
- ...

I have tried this but it doesn't work.

```
    <script>
        $(document).on('change','select[id$='item']', function(event){
            alert(event.target.id);
        });
    </script>
```

I want the id of element which triggered the event. Thanks

Comment: `this` inside the function should be the element that triggered the event - so `this.id` ... can you show the HTML - I think I may be wrong, the change event is on the <select>, you're saying *item*, do you mean the <option>?

Comment: You wrote `</script>` instead of `<script>`.  Was that a typo in your question or could this be the problem with your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your function: char escape. 
You need to change:

```
$(document).on('change','select[id$='item']', function(event){
```

to:

```
$(document).on('change','select[id$="item"]', function(event){
```

another way to escape char is:

```
$(document).on('change','select[id$=\'item\']', function(event){
```

For more info you may take a look to [Escape notation in string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)
So the snippet is:

```js
$(function () {
  $(document).on('change','select[id$="item"]', function(event){
    console.log("event.target.id=" + event.target.id + " or this.id=" + this.id);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<select id="id_form-0-item">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<select id="id_form-1-item">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<select id="id_form-2-item">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @AyushSrivastava I'm glad for you.

Answer (score 1):

Super simple:

```
</script>
    $(document).on('change','select[id$='item']', function(event){
        var id = this.id;
    });
</script>
```

then use `id` for whatever purpose you need.